# Reuse gradle.kts function

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have a multiproject gradle.kts setup and I would like to reuse a function, eg.

```kt
fun doSomethingWithString(string: String) { return string }
```

I then use the function within the `dependencies {}` block.

I would like to either:

- define the `fun` within the root `build.gradle.kts`
- define the `fun` within some other file which I could import within every subproject

Is this feasible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create your function in a [`buildSrc` project](https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:build_sources).

There are various ways to approach this. Here are just two examples for how this could be done. Both use the same `buildSrc/build.gradle.kts`:

```kt
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

#### Example: Shared Package-Level Function

You can create a package-level function, e.g., in `buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/myconvention/myconventions.kt`:

```kt
package myconvention

fun doSomethingWithString(string: String): String {
  return string + "321"
}
```

Then in your (sub)project build scripts, you can access the function as follows:

```kt
println(myconvention.doSomethingWithString("foo"))
```

#### Example: Precompiled Script Plugin

You can create the function as an extra property on the project in a [precompiled script plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:precompiled_plugins), e.g., if you have `buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/myproject.conventions.gradle.kts`:

```kt
val doSomethingWithString by extra(
  fun(string: String): String {
    return string + "123"
  }
)
```

Then in your (sub)project build scripts, you can access the function as follows:

```kt
plugins {
    id("myproject.conventions")
}
val doSomethingWithString: (String) -> String by extra

println(doSomethingWithString("foo"))
```

#### Minimal Working Configuration for the First Example

Complete root project directory structure (excl. [Gradle Wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) files):

```
├── mysub
│   └── build.gradle.kts
├── buildSrc
│   ├── build.gradle.kts
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── kotlin
│               └── myconvention
│                   └── myconventions.kt
└── settings.gradle.kts
```

- `mysub/build.gradle.kts` only contains `println(myconvention.doSomethingWithString("foo"))`
- `buildSrc/build.gradle.kts` and `buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/myconvention/myconventions.kt` have the exact content described above
- `settings.gradle.kts`:

```kt
rootProject.name = "my_test"
include("mysub")
```

When running `./gradlew projects` (using Gradle 6.7.1), the output contains the following, as expected:

```
> Configure project :mysub
foo321
```

Comment: The first way is what I would like to pursue. However it does not seem to work: Once I try to use the `myconvention.doSomethibg` within a subproject, it says "Unresolved reference" for the `myconvention`. I also tried `import myconvention.doSomething` with no luck. Note that the `buildSrc` project is not added within the `settings.gradle.kts` as that leads to an error too.

Comment: Thanks for considering my answer, @Vojtěch! I have updated it with a minimal, working example build configuration; I hope that works for you, too? How does your configuration differ from it? Can you maybe add a [mcve] to your question?

Comment: For me even when I just put the sample piece with `extra` into equivalent of `myconventions.kt`, extra is undefined

Comment: Did anyone ever figure this out?  The first example definitely doesn't work.  Not sure why this answer is accepted

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, the first option seemed to work well for me.  Just a question: did you find a way to import the namespace, so that you don't have to prefix with `myconvention` every time you call the function? `import myconvention` didn't seem to help at all.